# How to set a position and a style to a text?

Tags: c#, itext

I've created the following method to place text where i want in my document (based on a stackoverflow topic).

```
PdfContentByte cb = _pdfWriter.DirectContent;
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont();
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, size);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(x, y);
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.Stroke();
            cb.EndText();
```

My problem is Basefont dont support BOLD, UNDERLINE or ITALIC. So, what is the good way to set the position of text and apply a style to it ?

Thanks for reading and future answers.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the difference between a font family and a font.

**Helvetica** is an example of a font family. **Helvetica (regular)**, **Helvetica Bold**, **Helvetica Italic** and **Helvetica Bold Italic** are examples of *different* font.

Suppose that you've used the regular Helvetica when defining `bf`, then you are using one specific font. If you want the text to be bold, you need to use a *different* font, for instance a `bf_bold` instance that is defined using Helvetica Bold.

*Underline* isn't a property of a font. If you want to draw a line, you need to use `moveTo()`, `lineTo()` and `stroke()` operators.

All of this is very hard, and it surprises me that you want to do it this way. It's as if somebody has given you the *Advanced manual*, hiding the *Manual for Beginners* on purpose, just to make you suffer.

Why don't you use `ColumnText` to draw text with different styles at absolute positions? Where did you find the snippet from your question, and how come you didn't look at [the ColumnText examples that are available on the official iText web site](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=59)? If you're afraid to look at Java code, you can also find the C# port of the examples [here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178).

Comment: I've finaly found what i want to do, but i trust you when you say it's a hard way. I've short short deadline and the panic doesn't let's me learn IText in standard way (i search example of what i want and adapt it). but thanks a lot for answers